# A little help on properties Lebesgue integration.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Suppose $f$ is a nonnegative $\mathcal{M}-\text{measurable}$ function and $\{E\}_{n=1}^\infty\subset\mathcal{M}$ with $E_1\supset E_2 \supset \cdot \cdot \cdot $. Further suppose $\int_\mathbb{R}f \ d  \lambda<\infty.$ Prove that $$\large\int_{\cap_{n=1}^\infty E_n}f \ d\lambda=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\int_{E_n}f \ d\lambda .$$ 
I can use the fact that if $\{f_n\}_{n=1}^\infty$ is a monotone nonincreasing sequence of nonnegative Lebesgue measurable functions, and $\int f_1  \ d\lambda<\infty $. Then $$ \large \int_E \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}f_n  \ d\lambda = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int f_n \ d\lambda.$$
I was thinking that I shuold use $f_n = f \chi_{E_n} $ then $f_n$ is nonincreasing. So we have $$ \large\int_{E_n}\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f_n \ d\lambda = \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\int_{E_n} f_n \ d\lambda .$$ I also know that $\cap_{k=1}^nE_k=E_n$ and if we take the limit of both sides we get $\cap_{n=1}^\infty E_n=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} E_n$. I am just not sure what I should do next.

Answer (score 1):

Using $f_n=f\chi_{E_n}$ is a good idea.  After slightly rewriting, you have that

$\int \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n d\lambda=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \int_{E_n} f d\lambda$

Note that you have the right hand side of the equality you want to show.  What remains is to show that the integrand on the left hand side converges pointwise to the function you want (after rewriting $\int_{{\cap_{n=1}^\infty}E_n}fd\lambda$ as $\int f\chi_{{\cap_{n=1}^\infty}E_n}d\lambda$) ; that is, show that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f_n=f\chi_{{\cap_{n=1}^\infty}E_n}$.

Showing that $f\chi_{E_n}\rightarrow f\chi_{{\cap_{n=1}^\infty}E_n}$ pointwise is equivalent to showing that $\chi_{E_n}\rightarrow \chi_{{\cap_{n=1}^\infty}E_n}$ pointwise, which is easy to show using the assumptions on the $E_n$.

Let $\epsilon >0$ be given, and let $x\in (-\infty, \infty)$.  We want to show that there exists a positive integer $N$ such than $|\chi_{{\cap_{n=1}^\infty}E_n}(x)-\chi_{E_n}(x)|<\epsilon$ whenever $n\geq N$.  Either $x\in \cap_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ or $x\not \in \cap_{n=1}^\infty E_n$.

If $x\in \cap_{n=1}^\infty E_n$, then $\chi_{E_n}(x)=1$ for all $n$, and $\chi_{{\cap_{n=1}^\infty}E_n}(x)=1$ also. So let $N=1$. Then for all $n\geq N$, we have that $|\chi_{{\cap_{n=1}^\infty}E_n}(x)-\chi_{E_n}(x)|=0<\epsilon$ and we're done.

If $x\not \in \cap_{n=1}^\infty E_n$, then $x\not \in E_k$ for some integer $k$. Then, since $E_k\supseteq E_{k+1}\supseteq$..., $x\not \in$...

Can you finish it from here?

Comment: but $f_n$ is nonincreasing so how can we use the monotone convergence theorem?

Comment: I misspoke. I meant to cite the fact you mentioned that you are allowed to use.

Comment: Ahh sorry I should have read on after and I would have realized that.

Comment: If $x\not \in \cap_{n=1}^\infty E_n$, then $\chi_{E_n}(x)=0$ for all $n$, and $\chi_{{\cap_{n=1}^\infty}E_n}(x)=0$ and this is enough to show $\chi_{E_n}\rightarrow \chi_{{\cap_{n=1}^\infty}E_n}$ ?

Comment: Be careful. $x \not \in \cap_{n=1}^\infty E_n$ means that there exists some $k$ such that $x\not \in E_k$...

Comment: Ahh right so we have some k where $\chi_{E_k}(x)=0$ so $\chi_{{\cap_{n=1}^\infty}E_n}(x)=0$. If this is what we are saying I am still confused on how this shows that we have convergence. Sorry I'm an undergrad and this stuff is killing me:)

Comment: You need to justify more why $\chi_{\cap_{n=1}^\infty E_n}(x)=0$. You haven't used your assumptions on the $E_n$ yet. If $x\not \in E_k$, then... Also, do you understand why the only thing remaining to show in your proof is $\chi_{E_n}\rightarrow \chi_{\cap_{n=1}^\infty E_n}$?

Comment: I'm am still confused about what you are saying, it seems obvious that if x is not in the intersection then $\chi_{{\cap_{n=1}^\infty}E_n}(x)=0$ by definition of $\chi$ Im not sure why we need to use the assumption. It seems this would be true for any intersection.

Comment: Your first statement is not what you want; you still aren't using the fact that $E_1 \supseteq E_2 \supseteq$...   Also, you don't want an 'epsilon-delta' proof, but rather an 'epsilon-N' proof (we aren't showing one function is continuous, we are showing a sequence of functions converges pointwise). At this point, my advice is to try and write up an epsilon proof for why $\chi_{E_n}\rightarrow \chi_{\cap E_n}$.

Comment: Since $E_n$ is decreasing, we know $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}E_n = \cap_{n=1}^\infty E_n$, because $E_n = \cap_{k=1}^n E_k$. Is this not enough?

Comment: Again, I must apologize for misspeaking.  It is of course true that for $x$ not in the intersection of the $E_n$ that $\chi_{\cap E_n}(x)=0$.  The heart of the matter is why $\chi_{E_n}(x)\rightarrow 0$.  I apologize for causing such a confusion.